# Extra character placed in path of DSC config - Azure PS

Tags: json, azure, powershell, dsc

I'm trying to work out why I'm getting the error below; the path to the configuration.ps1 file should be configuration\configuration.ps1, however its failing as its reading it as configuration.0\configuration.ps1.

the whole error message is below, has anyone else come across this?

```
"status": "Failed",
  "error": {
    "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
    "message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.",
    "details": [
      {
        "code": "VMExtensionProvisioningError",
        "message": "VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'CreateADPDC'. Error message: \"The DSC Extension received an incorrect input: An error occurred while 
executing script or module 'configuration.ps1':  The term 'C:\\Packages\\Plugins\\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\\2.77.0.0\\bin\\..\\DSCWork\\configuration.0\\configuration.ps1' is not 
recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try 
again..\nPlease correct the input and retry executing the extension.\"."
      }
    ]
  }
}'
At line:4 char:14
+ ...             New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name "coredeployment1 ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet

New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 18:31:08 - VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'CreateADPDC'. Error message: "The DSC Extension received an incorrect input: An 
error occurred while executing script or module 'configuration.ps1':  The term 
'C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\2.77.0.0\bin\..\DSCWork\configuration.0\configuration.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable 
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again..
Please correct the input and retry executing the extension.".
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: it actually looks like a proper path. if you login to the vm does that when extracting configurations. you sure your configuration file is the same name as you think it is?

Comment: take a look at the accepted answer here ... powershell - Azure ARM DSC scale set deployment - cannot locate script - Stack Overflow — https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46621314/azure-arm-dsc-scale-set-deployment-cannot-locate-script ///// it seems to do with the _way_ you specify the path - apparently the file needs to be in the root - "file was /DSC/script.ps1. It should be /script.ps1".

Comment: @NorrinRad - you are very welcome! glad to have helped a tad ... [*grin*]